# How do I solve this do while looping error?

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, project, do-while

I'm working on a project on the side that was given by a computer science professor at my university. I don't have him, but I thought it'd be nice to try it out. The goal of the project is to have completed a successful book and cd rental "shop" that meets all the criteria.

Right now my problem is located within the part where I am supposed to give the user a way to modify existing customer information. In the ModifyCustomer method, I have defined, I have quite a bit of nested loops. Everything was working smoothly until I had to implement a do while loop over the entire method so that the user could again change existing customer information if need be. There are only two customers. Whenever I modify customer 1 multiple times, all of my switch statements work fine. HOWEVER, whenever I modify customer 2 multiple times, the compiler decides that it wants to skip to the bottom even when prompting the compiler to modify a certain aspect of a customer's information. The only thing I can edit for customer 2 is its address, but I cannot prompt the compiler to edit customer 2's name or phone number without it skipping to the bottom of the do while loop without allowing me to change a single thing. It's a good bit of code, so if anyone would like to copy and paste into their own IDE and help me figure out what the heck I did wrong, that'd be appreciated!

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShopWithMethods {

public static void main (String[] Args) {
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "n/a";
    String date1 = "n/a";
    String address = "n/a";
    String phone = "n/a";
    String decide = "n/a";
    String rentalRecord = "No books or CDs rented yet.";
    System.out.println("Welcome to Eli's bookshop and CD rental shop!");
    Addcustomer(name, address, phone, date1, rentalRecord);

}

private static void Addcustomer(String name, String address, String phone, String date1, String rentalRecord) {
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String decide;
    loop:
        while (true) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to create a customer profile with us? (Enter y or n):");
        decide = scan1.next();

        switch (decide) {

        case "y" : {
            System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
            scan1.nextLine();
            name = scan1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter your address: ");
            address = scan1.nextLine();
            break loop;

        }


        case "n" : {
            System.out.print("Okay, please visit us another time.");
            break loop;
        }

        default : {
            System.out.print("(Try again)  ");
        }

    }
            }

        loop:
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Enter your phone number(0000000000): ");
                phone = scan1.nextLine();
                if (phone.length() != 10) {
                    continue loop;
                }


                break loop;

            }

        loop:
            while(true) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Date(mm-dd-yyyy): ");

        date1 = scanner.next();

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date date2=null;
            try {

        date2 = dateFormat.parse(date1);
        } 
            catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                continue loop;
            }

            System.out.println("The date you've entered is: " + date2);
            break loop; 
            }



            String [][] CustomerProfile1 = {
                {"Name:", name},
                {"Address:", address},
                {"Phone Number:", phone},
                {"Enrollment Date:", date1},
                {"Rental Record:", rentalRecord}
        };

            System.out.println();
            loop:
                while(true) {
                    System.out.print("Adding a second customer, press c to continue: ");
                    decide = scan1.next();

            switch (decide.toLowerCase()) {

            case "c": {
                System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
                scan1.nextLine();
                name = scan1.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter your address: ");
                address = scan1.nextLine();
                break loop;

            }


            default : {
                System.out.print("(Try again)  ");
            }

        }
                }

            if (decide.equals("c")) {
            loop:
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Enter your phone number(0000000000): ");
                    phone = scan1.nextLine();
                    if (phone.length() != 10) {
                        continue loop;
                    }


                    break loop;

                }
            }

            if (decide.equals("c")) {
            loop:
                while(true) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the Date(mm-dd-yyyy): ");

            date1 = scanner.next();

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
            Date date2=null;
                try {

            date2 = dateFormat.parse(date1);
            } 
                catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue loop;
                }

                System.out.println("The date you've entered is: " + date2);
                break loop; 
                }
            }

                System.out.println();
                if (decide.equals("c")) {
                    String [][] CustomerProfile2 = {
                        {"Name:", name},
                            {"Address:", address},
                            {"Phone Number:", phone},
                            {"Enrollment Date:", date1},
                            {"Rental Record:", rentalRecord}
                    };

                    System.out.println("Customer profile 1: ");
                    for (String i []: CustomerProfile1) {
                        System.out.println();
                        for (String print1: i) {
                            System.out.print(print1 + " ");

                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Customer profile 2: ");
                    for (String j []: CustomerProfile2) {
                        System.out.println();
                        for (String print2: j) {
                            System.out.print(print2 + " ");

                        }
                    }

                }


                String [][] CustomerProfile2 = {
                        {"Name:", name},
                            {"Address:", address},
                            {"Phone Number:", phone},
                            {"Enrollment Date:", date1},
                            {"Rental Record:", rentalRecord}
                    };

                System.out.println();

                ModifyCustomer(CustomerProfile1, CustomerProfile2, name, address, phone, date1, rentalRecord);

}

private static void ModifyCustomer(String[][] customerProfile1, String[][] customerProfile2, String name,
        String address, String phone, String date1, String rentalRecord) {

    System.out.println();
    String decide;
    String change;
    String repeat;
    int modify;

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
    loop:
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to modify a customer? (Enter y or n): ");
            decide = scan1.next();

            switch (decide.toLowerCase()) {

            case "y" : {
                System.out.println();
                break loop;
            }
            case "n" : {
                System.out.println();
                break loop;
            }
            }
        }

    loop:
        while(true) {
    if (decide.equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to modify customer 1 or customer 2? ");
        modify = scan1.nextInt();
        switch (modify) {
        case 1:{
            System.out.println();
            break loop;
        }

        case 2: {
            System.out.println();
            break loop;
        }


        }
    }
        }


            loop:
                while(true) {
                    System.out.print("Would you like to modify the name, address, or phone?");
                    change = scan1.next();
            switch(change) {

            case "name": {
                if (modify == 1) {
                    System.out.print("Modify customer 1's name: ");
                    scan1.nextLine();
                    customerProfile1[0][1] = scan1.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Customer 1's updated profile: ");
                    for (String [] i: customerProfile1) {
                        System.out.println();
                        for (String printData1: i) {
                            System.out.print(printData1 + " ");
                        }
                    }
                if (modify == 2) {
                    System.out.print("Modify customer 2's name: ");
                    scan1.nextLine();
                    customerProfile2[0][1] = scan1.next();
                    System.out.println("Customer 2's updated profile: ");
                    for (String [] j: customerProfile2) {
                        System.out.println();
                        for (String printData2: j) {
                            System.out.print(printData2 + " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                break loop;
            }

            case "address": {
                if (modify == 1) {
                    System.out.print("Modify customer 1's address: ");
                    scan1.nextLine();
                    customerProfile1[1][1] = scan1.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Customer 1's updated profile: ");
                    for (String [] i: customerProfile1) {
                        System.out.println();
                        for (String printData1: i) {
                            System.out.print(printData1 + " ");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (modify == 2) {
                    System.out.print("Modify customer 2's addresss: ");
                    scan1.nextLine();
                    customerProfile2[1][1] = scan1.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Customer 2's updated profile: ");
                    for (String [] j: customerProfile2) {
                        System.out.println();
                        for (String printData2: j) {
                            System.out.print(printData2 + " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                break loop;
            }

            case "phone": {
                if (modify == 1) {
                    do {
                        System.out.print("Modify customer 1's phone number: ");
                        scan1.nextLine();
                        phone = scan1.nextLine();
                        customerProfile1[2][1] = phone;
                        System.out.println("Customer 1's updated profile: ");
                        for (String [] i: customerProfile1) {
                            System.out.println();
                            for (String printData1: i) {
                                System.out.print(printData1 + " ");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    while (phone.length() != 10);
                    if (phone.length() == 10) {
                        break loop;
                    }

                    if (modify == 2) {
                        do {
                            System.out.print("Modify customer 2's phone number: ");
                            scan1.nextLine();
                            phone = scan1.nextLine();
                            customerProfile2[2][1] = phone;
                            System.out.println("Customer 2's updated profile: ");
                            for (String [] j: customerProfile2) {
                                System.out.println();
                                for (String printData2: j) {
                                    System.out.print(printData2 + " ");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        while (phone.length() != 10);
                        if (phone.length() == 10) {
                            break loop;
                        }
                    }

                }
                break loop;
            }
}






}


        System.out.print("Would you like to modify anything else? (Enter y or n): ");
        repeat = scan1.next();
        if (repeat.equals("n")) {
            break;
        }
        else 
            continue;

    }
    while (repeat.equals("y"));



}
}
```

Comment: Working through the code but I would highly recommend trying to avoid this kind of coding, there's way too much going on in the code to keep track of and it's not well organised so errors will naturally take longer to find

Comment: Break your code up into small, discrete, *testable* methods with well defined inputs and outputs.  Once you've done that, the error will be isolated to 8-10 lines of code, and will likely be obvious.

Comment: I've actually solved my problem by coming up with a more efficient algorithm and organization! Thank you two for the tips!

Comment: Very good, if possible, post your solution